# DB2 Stored Procedure issue

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have a requirement to frame a query which will fetch all the tables from database and then have to reset one particular column value to 0 from each table. The problem is tables will be added dynamically in future and there is no fixed number of tables .

I'm pretty new to this DB2 and never wrote a stored procedure but i tried with the below procedure which I'm getting SQL state errors . Could anyone help me out in this issue please .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ResetCoulmnValues ()

BEGIN

DECLARE TABLE_NAME Varchar(50) ;

DECLARE COLUMN_NAME Varchar(50) ; 

DECLARE TableDetails CURSOR FOR
   SELECT TABNAME,COLNAME from SYSCAT.COLUMNS where tabschema = 'CALL' and TABNAME<>'ASC_TOTAL_CALL_CONTINUATION_EVENT';

OPEN TableDetails;

FETCH TableDetails
    INTO TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME;

UPDATE TABLE_NAME
    SET COLUMN_NAME = 0;

   CLOSE TableDetails ;
END;

CALL ResetCoulmnValues ()
```

Error:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
>   SQLERRMC=END-OF-STATEMENT;BLE_NAME Varchar(50);,
>   DRIVER=3.57.110 SQLState:  42601 ErrorCode: -104

Error occurred in:
CREATE PROCEDURE ResetCoulmnValues ()
BEGIN
DECLARE TABLE_NAME Varchar(50)

Comment: You need to study and learn how to use dynamic-sql. Your code cannot use a static UPDATE TABLE_NAME.. , because that table does not exist at compile-time. Instead it may exist at run time when the variable gets populated, so you need to change the code to compile at run time - this is called dynamic SQL. Study the IBM sample stored procedures which are both in the Db2 Knowledge Centre and in your SAMPLES folder on your Db2-server (if your Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows) , and learn about `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`  and `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and how to use them inside stored procedures.

Comment: Additionally you need to learn about looping over the cursor, and how to use exception handlers / testing for success/fail of statements.  It is wise to study samples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 before trigger syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579606/db2-before-trigger-syntax)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 Stored Procedure: Dynamically Building a Select Statement for cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410987/db2-stored-procedure-dynamically-building-a-select-statement-for-cursor)

Comment: I will make a note and will try this . Thank you guys for your suggestions, appreciate it .